# I want to create a Weebly site and have it show up as static pages on a Wordpress site

Tags: pages

My son knows how to use Weebly, but he is not familiar with Wordpress. He has been asked to create some static pages on an existing wordpress site (I believe it is Wordpress.org because he was given log-in information to get into the site.) Is there any way that he can create his pages using Weebly and have them redirected to show up as pages on the Wordpress site? This would buy him some time to come up to speed and learn Wordpress.

Also, once he creates the site in Weebly, is it difficult to migrate it to Wordpress?

He hasn't created the weekly site yet, but the Wordpress site already exists since there are a few people supporting and creating content for this site. Ideally, my son would create in Weebly and the pages he created would show up on the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iFrame to display a Weebly page in a Wordpress page, but that's it; display only. There's no direct data sharing. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that every time you said weekly you meant weebly, then no, it is entirely impossible to share content between weebly and wordpress. You can setup redirects or URL rewriting on the wordpress site to point to a weebly site, but there's no way to have weebly submit content to wordpress.

Just a note for future questions: wordpress.org does not host any sites, wordpress.com hosts sites. Org is for downloading wordpress for a standalone install. I'm not sure if that's what you meant, but I figured I'd clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/

You can use page scraping to filter and disply content on your wordpress blog.